# Individual push notification for Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

Im implented [this GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) example into my Android application. When I trigger a message it will be received by all devices, which have installed my app.

**Is it possible to address a single device by purpose (also with other libraries/technologies other than GCM)?**

Comment: you can do by upstream message notification of GCM

Comment: if you're not exhausted with your GCM implemantation, you can switch to FCM as it provides firebase console to send notification and is very easy to setup.you can always send notifiaction to single device if you have device token directly.

Comment: what do you mean by "also with other libraries/technologies other than GCM"? Not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is it possible to address a single device by purpose?**

Yes, of course, it is possible.
There are two ways.

**1. Using GCM Registration token :**

> You can target a single device using it's GCM registration token as mentioned
>   [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream).

```
{ 
   "data": {
      "score": "5x1",
      "time": "15:10"
   },

   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

**2. Using GCM Topics :**

> GCM topic messaging allows your app server to send a message to
>   multiple devices that have opted into a particular topic as mentioned 
>   [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

**Client Side :**

```
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {

    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);

        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/foo-bar", null);

}
```

**Server Side :**

```
{ 
    "data": {
       "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
     },

     "to": "/topics/foo-bar"
}
```

For both the ways,

Add your target device's `registration token string` or `topic name` under `to` section of a message request.

Hope it helps. :)